# What powers of $|x|$ belong to $L^1$?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Prove that $|x|^ {−qp} \in L^{1}(U)$, where $U=B_{1}(0)\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$. 
I think I could use polar coordinates to facilitate the work but not sure if it is useful.